# GUI: passing arguments to a function when pressing button

Tags: python, qt, button, pyside, argument-passing

my excuses if that question is very simple. I have a GUI with a few pushbuttons (QT with PySide). I want to connect 2 buttons with one function which is supposed to do the same thing with one difference. For that I need to pass an argument. Here is the type of code:

```
def test(flag):
    if flag:
        do something
    else:
        do something else

# button calls:
self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(test(True))
self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(test(False))
```

I have tried things as above, but it does not like the test(True). I have also played with lambda's and I am getting stuck at the same spot. So far I have been calling two separate functions, but that is not a good practice. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks

It works! Much simpler than I thought. Many thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by getting stuck? Lambdas should work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You said you used lambdas, did you try this

```
self.ui.button1.clicked.connect(lambda:test(True))
self.ui.button2.clicked.connect(lambda:test(False))
```

This should work.